# Cordova PhoneGap - Prevent user from returning to index.html page.

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've got a web application that I'm accessing using the PhoneGap AppBrowser.

I'm using the index.html page as a splash screen page and want to prevent the user from ever going back to it after they've been redirected to the application page via the JS that runs on that page. I've tried to go about it using `window.location.replace("www.myapp.com");` but this opens the page in the system browser.

I tried setting an event handler that would get called when the back button was pressed but when I return to this page, it doesn't work (I have to press the back button when I've reached this page to invoke it). To be honest, I'm a little confused about whether the application opens up in the Cordova webview or the app browser. I tried changing `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(encodeURI(url), '_self', 'location=no');` to `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', 'location=no');` but still end up with the same result.

How can I ensure that the user - upon clicking the back button - will not be able to return to the index.html page, but exit the application instead?

I'm using Cordova CLI 6.1.1 and testing on Android 5.x.

**index.js is as follows:**

```
$(function () {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

        var url = 'http://www.myapp.com';
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(encodeURI(url), '_self', 'location=no');
        }, 2500);

    };

    function onBackKeyDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(document.location.href.indexOf('asset/www/index.html') > 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, found the answer [here](https://cordovablogsblogs.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/handle-android-back-button-on-phonegap-inappbrowser/).

Just have to add the following listener to exit the application when the AppBrowser exits.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(encodeURI(url), '_self', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('exit', function () {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
});
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.